# GTFS-realtime-bindings for iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, encoding, protocol-buffers, gtfs

MTA Subway data (among other data) is formatted in GTFS-realtime. In order to convert the protobuf into a string representation I must run it through some Google protobuf tools using gtfs-realtime.proto. The only problem is that, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings#other-languages), the gtfs-realtime-bindings are available only for

- NET
- Java
- JavaScript / Node.js
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby
- Golang

Additionally,

> We don't provide generated code for C++, use the official protoc compiler for that (from [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads) or [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf))

None of these are Swift or Objective C. While there is an open [issue/request](https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings/issues/3) for a Swift/Objective C version from 2016, I was wondering what I can do currently in order to do this. As of now, the only viable solution I see is to have a server parse the data and then GET the parsed data (JSON encoded?) from that server instead of directly from the MTA.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/objective-c-generated) is the Google page for protocol buffers. I am not sure, but is there some way to use what is there to read the GTFS-realtime data.

Is that the best path forward? Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Tony Laudig, having your app directly communicate with the MTA is a breach of their terms and conditions which you almost definitely would have had to agree to in order to get an api key.

Breaking terms and conditions is generally a pretty bad idea. In the case of this API, it seems like your key will be revoked.

Thus, I would **not** suggest using the library in Tony’s answer. Instead, do what you proposed:

> Have a server parse the data and then GET the parsed data (JSON encoded? [—sounds good]) from that server instead of directly from the MTA.

Any of the languages you listed will do the job, it’s just a matter of which you’re most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [official library](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/objectivec) in Objective C for parsing Protobuf. You can [compile classes](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/objective-c-generated#invocation) from the GTFS-rt standard and the MTA extension .proto files.

It looks like your planned usage, having the app connect to the MTA directly, doesn't conform to the [MTA terms and conditions](http://web.mta.info/developers/developer-data-terms.html):

> 1. In developing your app, you will provide that the MTA data feed is
>      available to others only from a non-MTA server. Accordingly, you will
>      download and store the MTA data feed on a non-MTA server which users
>      of your App will access in order to obtain data. MTA prohibits the
>      development of an app that would make the data available to others
>      directly from MTA's server(s).